# zlib error when I try to install node packeges

Tags: node.js, sqlite, npm, electron

I have Probleme with installing new packages with npm after I did an npm update with this commande : `npm install -g npm@latest` in order to fix a problem related to install sqlite3 in node_modules of an electron app.

But after whene I try to run the commande of sqlite3 :  `npm install sqlite3 --save` or any other commande to install a new package it give this error:

```
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Desktop_stuffs\workspace\terrains\Gestion Ecole\electron-quick-start\node_modules\.staging\sqlite3-2e42d809'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Desktop_stuffs\workspace\terrains\Gestion Ecole\electron-quick-start\node_modules\.staging\sax-8976b37c\lib\sax.js'
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.0.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\rijs.resdir\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null

npm ERR! zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-31T22_03_39_222Z-debug.log
```

running `npm version` gives :

```
{'electron-quick-start': '1.0.0', 
npm: '6.10.2',                   
ares: '1.13.0',                  
cldr: '32.0',                    
http_parser: '2.7.0',            
icu: '60.1',                     
modules: '59',                   
nghttp2: '1.25.0',               
node: '9.2.0',                   
openssl: '1.0.2m',               
tz: '2017c',                     
unicode: '10.0',                 
uv: '1.16.1',                    
v8: '6.2.414.44-node.11',        
zlib: '1.2.11' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue, it was just a compatibility problem between NPM and node, I used the last version of NPM with an old version of node, So I just downloaded the last version of node to update it, and the installation commands run normally.

Comment: Still have this issue! Very frustrating